# Simple restrictions/constraint for multiple imputation (MICE) in R

Tags: r, constraints, r-mice, imputation

I want to perform multiple imputation for a set of variables using the *[MICE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html)* package in R.

```r
# Example data
data <- data.frame(
    gcs = c(3, 10, NA, NA, NA, 15, 14, 15, 15, 14, 15, NA, 13, 15, 15),
    hf = c(50, 66, 78, 99, NA, NA, 56, 55, NA, 76, 98, 105, NA, NA, 65),
    ...
)
```

The minimum for `gcs` is **3** and the maximum is **15**, and it may not be a fractional number, how can I set these constraints in *MICE*? Same goes for `hf`, but this one only has a bottom limit of **0**.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78632/multiple-imputation-for-missing-values should help

Comment: @user20650 It is a solution, but I wonder if there's no easier solution. I'd have to rewrite imputation methods for 100+ variables although I only want to **min**, **max** and **round**.

Comment: If you're hesitant to use a fully parametric method, you can try the `pmm` method in `mice` (predictive mean matching). Alternatively, you could try simple rounding or adaptive rounding procedures to get the data "look" like you want. Note, however, than nicely-looking data don't necessarily produce the least bias, and using a parametric model may actually work quite well.